# PHP - Sort by month but the data type is varchar?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i want to fetched all the data order in month but my problem is the data type of month to my database is varchar can someone give me ideas how to do it?

here is the structure of my sql
[image]

here is the output of the query to the events

[image]

and here is the code of my events

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
           <div class="title2">
                          <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Upcoming Events</h2>
          </div>
       <div class="fix sidebar floatright">
            <div class="fix single_sidebar">
                <div class="events">

                    <?php
                    include_once('connection.php');
                    $sql ="SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY month";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                $month = $row['month'];
                                $day = $row['day'];
                                $year = $row['year'];
                                $etitle = $row['event_title'];
                                $stime = $row['start_time'];
                                $etime = $row['end_time'];
                                $evenue = $row['event_venue'];
                         ?>
                         <div class="fix single_events">
                                    <div class="date">
                                         <span class="month"><?php echo $month; ?></span>
                                          <h1 class="day"><?php echo $day; ?></h1>
                                     </div>
                                    <h2><?php echo $etitle; ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php echo $stime; ?> - <?php echo $etime; ?></p>
                                    <p><?php echo $evenue; ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                   <?php
                         }
                    ?>


                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: _Never_ store dates in a `varchar`, store as `datetime` instead, this is the easiest solution to your problem.  If you show us actual output from a query, someone may give you a workaround.

Comment: It would give you less headaches in the future if you changed your column type. A work around would be to use MySQL's [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) -> `SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY FIELD(month, 'January', 'February', ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `month` is a string, not a numeric value.

Without knowing the values, it is hard to suggest a particular solution.  But here is one idea:

```
order by field(month, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
```